# how to access a java variable in strings.xml

Tags: java, android

How can I access a static `java` variable in a resource in `strings.xml` in the android studio?

I have a variable like this:

```
public static final String NUM_OF_DAYS = "10";
```

Now,
I want to use this somehow in `strings.xml` in a resource.

EDIT:

I just want to use the `string.xml` resource (which will access `NUM_OF_DAYS`) in a java file.

Comment: You **can't** access Java objects from a resource file.

Comment: @Rotwang I didn't  know whether it is possible or not, which is why I asked the question in the first place. Aren't stack exchange sites supposed to be for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your variable like this

```
public static final String NUM_OF_DAYS = "10";
```

string.xml

```
<string name="days">No of days: %s</string>
```

Java class

```
YOUR_VIEW.settext(getString(R.string.days, NUM_OF_DAYS));
```

Comment: The OP asked the other way around: Given a variable in Java, he thinks he can access it from a resource file. Which is **impossible**.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can not do such thing 
we do not edit string.xml from java code

Comment: Not what the OP asked: Given a variable in Java, he thinks he can access it from a resource file. Which is **impossible**.

Answer (score 0):

Because getString() is non-static you need a static Context for that.

In manifest file declare following

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.YourApplication">

</application>
```

Then wripte following class

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YourApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return YourApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Now you can use static context everywhere you need

```
      private static final String NUM_OF_DAYS = YouApplication.getAppContext()
.getString(R.string.yourString);
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked: Given a variable in Java, he thinks he can access it from a resource file. Which is **impossible**.